# Exception when path variable contains special characters like ~!@#$%^&*()<>

Tags: java, spring, rest, backbone.js

Spring throws exception if the path variable contains special characters. I have tried the following solution :-

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

but even after doing this i am unable to solve the issue. I have follwoing url-pattern /editMode/*. But still it dosent works even after changing url pattern.
Also i am using backbone1.1.2 framework as front-end which internally used encodeURIComponent but still problem persists.

Comment: Could you please add the exception to your question? Also, where do you have the url pattern defined? In the DispatcherServlet config?

Comment: Special chars should be encoded ie. `&` should be `&amp;` for instance else it isn't a valid URL.

Comment: @Kuurde I have defined the url pattern in web.xml and I am getting the following exception :- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error). The problem is with # in ~!@#$%^&*()<> d data i am sending to path variable.

Comment: M.Deinum is there any way to do it on server side ?..

Comment: @Kuurde if i am giving the path variable as ~!@..its working fine. But with ~!@# its not working correctly and this works fine even after not adding filter and filter mapping in web.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try url encoding the path variable like this:

```
localhost/editMode?var=example%23
```

if you want to send variable 'example#'

[HTML URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

If you create these urls on the server side you can use utility classes to URL encode them. Example: [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)

Comment: As i am using backbone framework wherein i cant encode the url..can you please suggest some way to encode it on spring side ?

Comment: Backbone? Your question is tagged with java, spring and rest .. I'm not familiar with backbone but it would surprise me if it wasn't possible. I suggest you improve the original question with the whole context of your problem. Be sure to add code fragments and all relevant technologies used.

Comment: As i am using spring framework...i am still not able to encode the url using url encoder ..Is there anyother to do it using spring mvc framework ?

Comment: Please edit the original question with code fragments as it is really hard to figure out what exactly the problem is. You have a backbone frontend that is creating requests to send to a spring backend? Please provide a sample of code that is not working.

Comment: by default backbone encodes it using encodeUriComponent... but still problem persists..

Comment: Code :-
 // Default URL for the model's representation on the server -- if you're
    // using Backbone's restful methods, override this to change the endpoint
    // that will be called.
    url: function() {
      var base =
        _.result(this, 'urlRoot') ||
        _.result(this.collection, 'url') ||
        urlError();
      if (this.isNew()) return base;
      return base.replace(/([^\/])$/, '$1/') + encodeURIComponent(this.id);
    }

Comment: If backbone uses the `encodeURIComponent` function this should be enough because `encodeURIComponent('#') = "%23"`. What does the request look like when it arrives at the Spring backend?

Answer (score 0):

As I was using backbone framework so i have overidden the url formation function.With the help of encodeURIComponent i was able to encode the name and spring automatically decoded the name. Now everything works perfectly :).
Thanks to Kuurde and M.Deinum for pointing me in right direction.